# Read and Write in C with lock (POSIX)

Tags: c, locking, posix

Hello I m student in informatics, I try to do a program where I lock/ unlock folder.

I put the complete program for you can try.  I can compile and run it but I m always blocked.
I don't know how to read in the file (I always have a return -1 with read.. )

I don't ask we correct all my code, just to show me what I do wrong with POSIX

Here my probel with read (return -1), 
I want my program create the file if is not exist but I don't know if it s possible.
How verify if the file is open ? I didn't find a way.
This function add a struc Owner in the file "PATH_FILE_OWNER"  Before add  he lock, verify if a OWNER have already the same ID than the new and if not add a new Owner to the file.

```
void addOwner()
{
    proprietaire* proprio = (proprietaire*)malloc(sizeof(proprietaire));
    if(proprio == NULL){
        perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int fd=open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    struct flock verrou;
    verrou.l_type=F_WRLCK;
    verrou.l_whence=verrou.l_start=verrou.l_len=0;



    while((fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) )== -1 && (errno == EACCES || errno == EAGAIN)){
        sleep(5);
        printf("Verrouiller\n");
    }


    int idDispo = FALSE,
        id;
    while(idDispo == FALSE)
    {
    cleanBuffer();
    printf("Entrez un identifiant non utilise\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    printf("id:  %d\n", id);


        // verifie si l'id est utilisé
        int trouve = FALSE, temp;
        while((temp = read(fd, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire))) != 0 && trouve == FALSE)
        {
            // I have add this for verify the error, it is right ? (if yes I ll do every where :)
            if(temp < 0){
                printf("Boucle %d\n", temp); 
                perror("erreur");
                printf("errno=%d\n", errno);
                exit(1);
            }

            if(proprio->identifiant == id){
                trouve = TRUE;
            }
        }

        // si l'id est utilisé redemande un autre id et refait une recherche,
        // sinon sort de la boucle et continue
        if(trouve == TRUE){
            printf("Identifiant deja utilise\n");
        } else {
            idDispo = TRUE;
        }
    }

    // demande le reste des info et initialise la structure
    proprio->identifiant = id;
    printf("Entrez son nom:\n");
    scanf("%s",proprio->nom);
    printf("Entrez son prenom:\n");
    scanf("%s",proprio->prenom);
    printf("Entrez son adresse:\n");
    scanf("%s",proprio->adresse);
    proprio->nbVoiture = 0;

       // test affichage
    printf("Id : %d\n", proprio->identifiant);
    printf("Nom: %s\n", proprio->nom);
    printf("Prenom: %s\n", proprio->prenom);
    printf("Adresse: %s\n", proprio->adresse);
    printf("Nombre de voiture posseder: %d\n\n", proprio->nbVoiture);

    // j'enregistrer le proprietaire
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    write(fd, proprio , sizeof(proprio));

    // je deverrouille
    verrou.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) == -1){
        perror("Impossible de deverouiller le record");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(fd);
    free(proprio);
}
```

Here the full code:

```
#if defined(linux) || defined(__linux__) || defined(unix) || defined (__unix__) || defined (__APPLE__)
    #define mrpropre system("clear")
    #else
    #define mrpropre system("cls")
    #endif

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>


    #define TAILLE_NOM_MARQUE 20
    #define TAILLE_NOM_MODELE 10
    #define TAILLE_NOM_COULEUR 10
    #define TAILLE_NOM_PLAQUE 7

    #define TAILLE_NOM_PROPRIETAIRE 20
    #define TAILLE_PRENOM_PROPRIETAIRE 20
    #define TAILLE_ADRESSE_PROPRIETAIRE 40


    #define FALSE 0
    #define TRUE  1

    #define PATH_FILE_OWNER "fichProprio.bin"
    #define PATH_FILE_CAR   "fichVoiture.bin"


    typedef struct voiture
    {
        char nomMarque[TAILLE_NOM_MARQUE];
        char nomModele[TAILLE_NOM_MODELE];
        char couleur[TAILLE_NOM_COULEUR];
        char plaque[TAILLE_NOM_PLAQUE];
        int idProprietaire;

    } voiture;

    typedef struct proprietaire
    {
        int identifiant;
        char nom[TAILLE_NOM_PROPRIETAIRE];
        char prenom[TAILLE_PRENOM_PROPRIETAIRE];
        char adresse[TAILLE_ADRESSE_PROPRIETAIRE];
        int nbVoiture;

    } proprietaire;

    char menu();

    void showOwnerWithCar();

    void addOwner();

    void addCar();

    void updateOwner();

    void updateCar();

    void deleteOwner();

    void deleteCarID(int);

    void deleteCar();

    int addCarToOwner(int, int);

    void cleanBuffer();
    int main(void)
    {
        int fin=0;
        while(fin == 0)
        {
            mrpropre;
        cleanBuffer();
            char choixMenu = menu();
            switch(choixMenu)
            {
            case '0': // Quitter
                fin = 1;
                break;
            case '1':
                showOwnerWithCar();
                break;
            case '2':
                addOwner();
                break;
            case '3':
                addCar();
                break;
            case '4':
                updateOwner();
                break;
            case '5':
                updateCar();
                break;
            case '6':
                deleteOwner();
                break;
            case '7':
                deleteCar();
                break;
            default:
                printf("Erreur, aucun choix \n");
                getchar();
                break;

            }

        }
        return 0;
    }


    char menu()
    {
        printf("\nQue voulez-vous faire ?\n-------------------\n\n");
        printf("\t 1) Afficher un proprietaire et ces voiture\n");
        printf("\t 2) Ajouter un proprietaire\n");
        printf("\t 3) Ajouter une voiture (elle devra etre liee a un proprietaire)\n");
        printf("\t 4) Mise a jour des informations d'un proprietaire\n");
        printf("\t 5) Mise a jour des informations d'une voiture\n");
        printf("\t 6) Supprimer un proprietaire et ces voitures\n");
        printf("\t 7) Supprimer une voiture\n");
        printf("\t 0) Quitter le programme\n");
        return getchar();
    }


    void showOwnerWithCar(){

        // on cherche le propriétaire
        printf("Entrez l'identifiant du proprietaire\n");
        int idChercher; 
        scanf("%d", &idChercher);

        proprietaire* proprio = (proprietaire*)malloc(sizeof(proprietaire));
        if(proprio == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fdOwner = open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
        int trouve = FALSE;

        while(read(trouve == FALSE && fdOwner, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire)) != 0)
        {
        printf("ici1\t");
            if(proprio->identifiant == idChercher)
            {
                trouve = TRUE;
            }
        }
        close(fdOwner);
        printf("ici2\t");
        voiture * car = (voiture*)malloc(sizeof(voiture));
        voiture * tabVoiture = malloc(proprio->nbVoiture * sizeof(voiture));
        int fdCar = open(PATH_FILE_CAR, O_RDONLY);

        // ensuite on cherche ces voitures
        int nbVoitureTrouver = 0;
        while(read(fdCar, car, sizeof(voiture)) != 0 && nbVoitureTrouver < proprio->nbVoiture)
        {
            if(proprio->identifiant == idChercher)
            {
                tabVoiture[nbVoitureTrouver] = *car;
                nbVoitureTrouver++;
            }
        }
        close(fdCar);
        free(car);


        // on affiche le propriétaire
        printf("Id : %d\n", proprio->identifiant);
        printf("Nom: %s\n", proprio->nom);
        printf("Prenom: %s\n", proprio->prenom);
        printf("Adresse: %s\n", proprio->adresse);
        printf("Nombre de voiture posseder: %d\n\n", proprio->nbVoiture);

        // ensuite ces voitures
        int nbCar;
        for(nbCar=0;nbCar<proprio->nbVoiture;nbCar++){
            printf("Marque : %s\n", tabVoiture[nbCar].nomMarque);
            printf("Modele : %s\n", tabVoiture[nbCar].nomModele);
            printf("Couleur : %s\n",tabVoiture[nbCar].couleur);
            printf("Plaque : %s\n", tabVoiture[nbCar].plaque);
        }

        // on vide la mémoire
        free(proprio);
        for(nbCar=0;nbCar<proprio->nbVoiture;nbCar++){
            free(tabVoiture + nbCar);
        }

    }



    void addOwner()
    {
        proprietaire* proprio = (proprietaire*)malloc(sizeof(proprietaire));
        if(proprio == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        struct flock verrou;
        verrou.l_type=F_WRLCK;
        verrou.l_whence=verrou.l_start=verrou.l_len=0;



        while((fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) )== -1 && (errno == EACCES || errno == EAGAIN)){
            sleep(5);
            printf("Verrouiller\n");
        }


        int idDispo = FALSE,
            id;
        while(idDispo == FALSE)
        {
        cleanBuffer();
        printf("Entrez un identifiant non utilise\n");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        printf("id:  %d\n", id);


            // verifie si l'id est utilisé
            int trouve = FALSE, temp;
            while((temp = read(fd, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire))) != 0 && trouve == FALSE)
            {
                // I have add this for verify the error, it is right ? (if yes I ll do every where :)
                if(temp < 0){
                    printf("Boucle %d\n", temp); 
                    perror("erreur");
                    printf("errno=%d\n", errno);
                    exit(1);
                }

                if(proprio->identifiant == id){
                    trouve = TRUE;
                }
            }

            // si l'id est utilisé redemande un autre id et refait une recherche,
            // sinon sort de la boucle et continue
            if(trouve == TRUE){
                printf("Identifiant deja utilise\n");
            } else {
                idDispo = TRUE;
            }
        }

        // demande le reste des info et initialise la structure
        proprio->identifiant = id;
        printf("Entrez son nom:\n");
        scanf("%s",proprio->nom);
        printf("Entrez son prenom:\n");
        scanf("%s",proprio->prenom);
        printf("Entrez son adresse:\n");
        scanf("%s",proprio->adresse);
        proprio->nbVoiture = 0;

           // test affichage
        printf("Id : %d\n", proprio->identifiant);
        printf("Nom: %s\n", proprio->nom);
        printf("Prenom: %s\n", proprio->prenom);
        printf("Adresse: %s\n", proprio->adresse);
        printf("Nombre de voiture posseder: %d\n\n", proprio->nbVoiture);

        // j'enregistrer le proprietaire
        lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
        write(fd, proprio , sizeof(proprio));

        // je deverrouille
        verrou.l_type = F_UNLCK;
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) == -1){
            perror("Impossible de deverouiller le record");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(fd);
        free(proprio);
    }


    void addCar()
    {
        voiture* car = (voiture*)malloc(sizeof(voiture));
        if(car == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_CAR, O_APPEND|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        struct flock verrou;
        verrou.l_type=F_WRLCK;
        verrou.l_whence=verrou.l_start=verrou.l_len=0;


        int res, id;
        while( res == 0 )
        {
            printf("Entrer l'identifiant du proprietaire\n");
            scanf("%d", &id);
            res = addCarToOwner(1, id);
        }

        if(res == 1)
        {
            printf("Id valide\n");
            car->idProprietaire = id;
            printf("Entrez sa marque:\n");
            scanf("%s",car->nomMarque);
            printf("Entrez son modele:\n");
            scanf("%s",car->nomModele);
            printf("Entrez sa couleur:\n");
            scanf("%s",car->couleur);
            printf("Entrez son numero de plaque:\n");
            scanf("%s",car->plaque);


            // je verrouille le fichier
            while ( (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) )== -1 && (errno == EACCES  || errno == EAGAIN) ){
                sleep(5);
            }

            // j'enregistre la voiture
            lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
            write(fd , car, sizeof(car));

            // je deverrouille le fichier
            verrou.l_type = F_UNLCK;
            if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) == -1){
                perror("Impossible de deverouiller le record");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        free(car);
        close(fd);
    }


    void updateOwner()
    {
        proprietaire* proprio = (proprietaire*)malloc(sizeof(proprietaire));
        if(proprio == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        struct flock verrou;
        verrou.l_type=F_WRLCK;
        verrou.l_whence=verrou.l_start=verrou.l_len=0;

        printf("Id du proprietaire: \n");
        int id; scanf("%d",&id);

        while((fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) )== -1 && (errno == EACCES || errno == EAGAIN)){
            sleep(5);
        }

        // je cherche la personne concerner et la modifie si elle existe
        int trouve = FALSE;
        while(read(fd, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire)) != 0 && trouve == FALSE){
            if(proprio->identifiant == id){
                trouve = TRUE;
                printf(" L'adresse est %s\n Entrez la nouvelle adresse:\n", proprio->adresse);
                scanf("%s", proprio->adresse);
                lseek(fd, -sizeof(proprio) , SEEK_CUR);
                write(fd, proprio , sizeof(proprio));
                }
        }

        if(trouve == FALSE) printf("ID invalide\n");

        // je deverrouille le fichier
        verrou.l_type = F_UNLCK;
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) == -1)
            perror("Impossible de deverouiller le record");

        close(fd);
        free(proprio);
    }



    void updateCar()
    {
        voiture* car = (voiture*)malloc(sizeof(voiture));
        if(car == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        struct flock verrou;
        verrou.l_type=F_WRLCK;
        verrou.l_whence=verrou.l_start=verrou.l_len=0;

        char numPlaque[TAILLE_NOM_PLAQUE];
        printf("Entrez la plaque d'immatriculation du véhicule");
        scanf("%s", numPlaque);

        // je verouille
        while((fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) )== -1 && (errno == EACCES || errno == EAGAIN)){
            sleep(5);
        }

        // je recherche la voiture portant ce numero de plaque
        int trouve = FALSE;
        while(read(fd, car, sizeof(voiture)) != 0 && trouve == FALSE){
            // si je la trouve je modifie sa couleur
            if(strcmp(numPlaque, car->plaque) == 0){
                trouve = TRUE;
                printf("Entrez la nouvelle couleur");
                scanf("%s", car->couleur);
                lseek(fd, -sizeof(car) , SEEK_CUR);
                write(fd , car , sizeof(car));
            }
        }

            // je deverrouille le fichier
            verrou.l_type = F_UNLCK;
            if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) == -1){
                perror("Impossible de deverouiller le record");
                exit(1);
            }

            if(trouve == FALSE){
                printf("Voiture inconnue");
            }

            free(car);
    }

    void deleteOwner(){
        proprietaire* proprio = (proprietaire*)malloc(sizeof(proprietaire));
        if(proprio == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
        int fdNew=open("tempOwner.dat", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);

        int id;
        printf("Entrez l'identifiant du proprietaire a supprimer\n");
        scanf("%d", &id);


        int trouve = FALSE;
        while(read(fd, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire)) != 0)
        {
            if(proprio->identifiant == id){
                trouve = TRUE;
            } else {
                write( fdNew, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire));
            }
        }

        if(trouve == TRUE){
            rename("tempOwner.dat", PATH_FILE_OWNER);
            deleteCarID(id);
            printf("Supression du proprietaire\n");
        } else {
            printf("id invalide");
        }
        free(proprio);
    }

    void deleteCarID(int id){
        voiture* car = (voiture*)malloc(sizeof(voiture));
        if(car == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_CAR, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
        int fdNew=open("tempCar.dat", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);
        int trouve = FALSE;
        while(read(fd, car, sizeof(voiture)) != 0)
        {
            if(!car->idProprietaire == id){
                trouve = TRUE;
                write( fdNew, car, sizeof(proprietaire));
            }
        }

        if(trouve == TRUE){
            rename("tempCar.dat", PATH_FILE_CAR);
            printf("Supression des voitures\n");
        }
        free(car);
    }

    void deleteCar(){

        voiture* car = (voiture*)malloc(sizeof(voiture));
        if(car == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        char numPlaque[TAILLE_NOM_PLAQUE];
        printf("Entrez le numero de plaque de la voiture a supprimer\n");
        scanf("%s", numPlaque);

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_CAR, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
        int fdNew=open("tempCar.dat", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);
        int trouve = FALSE;
        while(read(fd, car, sizeof(voiture)) != 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(numPlaque, car->plaque) == 0){
                trouve = TRUE;
            } else {
                write(fdNew, car, sizeof(proprietaire));
            }
        }

        if(trouve == TRUE){
            rename("tempCar.dat", PATH_FILE_CAR);
            printf("Supression des voitures\n");
            addCarToOwner(-1, car->idProprietaire);
        }
        free(car);
    }

    // -1 pas de fichier
    // 0 id correspond pas
    // 1 ok
    int addCarToOwner(int nb, int id){
        proprietaire* proprio = (proprietaire*)malloc(sizeof(proprietaire));
        if(proprio == NULL){
            perror("L'allocation n'a pu etre réalisee\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int fd=open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        struct flock verrou;
        verrou.l_type=F_WRLCK;
        verrou.l_whence=verrou.l_start=verrou.l_len=0;

        int res = 0,
            trouve = FALSE;

        res = 0;


        // je verrouille le fichier des proprietaires
       while((fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) )== -1 && (errno == EACCES || errno == EAGAIN)){
            sleep(5);
        }

        // je cherche le proprietaire dans le fichier
        while(read(fd, proprio, sizeof(proprietaire)) != 0 && trouve == FALSE){
            if(proprio->identifiant == id){
                trouve = TRUE;
                res = 1;

                if(nb>0){
                    proprio->nbVoiture++;
                } else {
                    if(proprio->nbVoiture>0){
                        proprio->nbVoiture--;
                    }
                }
                lseek(fd, -sizeof(proprio) , SEEK_CUR);
                write(fd, proprio , sizeof(proprio));
            }
        }

        // je deverrouille le fichier
        verrou.l_type = F_UNLCK;
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &verrou) == -1){
            perror("Impossible de deverouiller le record");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(fd);
        free(proprio);
        return res;
    }

    void cleanBuffer(){
        while( getchar() != '\n');
    }
```

P.S my excuse for my english, and the no respect of the syntax for ask my quetion. I ll try to do better next time. I actually ask just for function addOwner(); with your help I ll try to debug all my program if possible.

Thx u for all your are nice :)

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow down the code to the parts that you have problems with.

Comment: Sorry I want show all if anybody want run it.

For the moment I try to user these functions: 
showOwnerWithCar()
addOwner()

if I resolve my problem in these I can surely resolve alone my problem in the others function.

My problem is than it s difficult to have information about POSIX in french..  My english level is low but I have already pass 4 days to resolve all my problem

Comment: It would help if you could copy the line(s) you're having trouble with (i.e. the line where you get -1 back) and put those in a separate code block. That way we can see where exactly your problem occurs. It's good that you included all of the code but you should make your question as accessible as possible (e.g. by adding those few extra lines).

Comment: Sorry I have take out the function I try to resolve. All my program bug mu surely with the same problem everywhere.   I have develop little bit more my problem and let the full code at the end (if anybody want try it) I m sure 90% of my error is the same everywhere.   


Thx u a lot

Comment: What is the value of `errno` when the `read()` fails (returns -1)? Try adding a call to `perror()` after the line `printf("Boucle %d\n", temp);`

Comment: I have add  
perror("error" );
printf("errno=%d\n", errno);

output:
Boucle -1
error: Bad file descriptor
errno=9
Boucle -1
error: Bad file descriptor
errno=9
Boucle -1
error: Bad file descriptor
errno=9
...

Comment: errno=9 -> EBADF  fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for reading.

Comment: Oh thx u 

if the file isn't exist he didn't create alone?   With 
how can I verify if the file already exist and create 1 alone ?

Comment: I have search how can I verify if the file already exist and I have add in the menu of my programe (in first)
int fd = open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_CREAT);
close(fd);
fd = open(PATH_FILE_CAR, O_CREAT);
close(fd);

The file exist now but I have still output:
Boucle -1 error: Bad file descriptor errno=9

Comment: You spent four days finding out that the file didn't exist?

Comment: Not only for it, I have first start with FILE *.. like I m habit before learn than I should use low level . I didn't know nothing about it so I have learn to open, close, lock, ..  And I work to little bit on other programs when I m tired

Answer (score 2):

Open the file like this:

```
fd = open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
```

Note that you still need to specify an access mode (O_RDWR), and the file mode flags are required for newly created files. That should fix your problem.

Also, you should add error checking for `open()` and also for the preceding `malloc()`.

**Edit**

You had further issues with writing the data. An incomplete record is written because you are only writing `sizeof(proprio)` bytes. `proprio` is declared as a *pointer* to a struct and it's size is therefore the size of a pointer (8 bytes on your 64bit machine). Change your write to:

```
ssize_t n = write(fd, proprio , sizeof(proprietaire));
```

so that you are writing the number of bytes required for the `struct proprietaire` (88 bytes for 64bit machine). It's important to check the return value from `write()` to ensure that the correct number of bytes were written, or to check for errors.

Comment: I have modify like it in the functions, the file is create but I have always error = 9

Comment: Added file mode flags to open()

Comment: At least on Linux, errno 9 is EBADF (i.e. your open call failed).  perror() after the read call will give you similar information.  If you'll add perror() after your open as well, it will give you an idea of what's wrong there.

Comment: Re I have again a problem.  When I write on the file 

exemple this data: 

Id: 123
Nom: Jojo
Prenom: Mar
Adresse: 40ruede
nbCar: 0

In the file I have just: 
{###Jojo


Why didn't have all the record ?

Comment: And I have again a question, is it possible to open a file in      "O_RDONLY | O_APPEND" ?  Because I think write isn't work like I want. Write do empty the file before write again. 

I want know too if:

    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    write(fd, proprio , sizeof(proprio));

write all the struct because I haven't all the information (sizeof(proprio is good? )

Comment: Ok I have modify my write (and other in my code)  I want to ask you if I should do to for   lseek(fd, -sizeof(proprio), SEEK_CUR);

Comment: Almost. To update the most recent record that was read you would need to `lseek(fd, -sizeof(proprietaire), SEEK_CUR);` to get back to the beginning of that record. Note that it's `sizeof(proprietaire)`, not `sizeof(proprio)` which is only 8 bytes. But if the record was not found and you want to add a new one to the end of the file, you can call `write()` without seeking (or call `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` if you want).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return code from open().  If your file doesn't already exist, the open will fail, and then your read() call will fail with EBADF.

It sounds like you want to add the O_CREAT flag to your open() call, so that the file will be created if it doesn't already exist.

At this point, I don't think your lock has anything to do with your problems.

Comment: Hi,thx u for your help.  I have add:

int fd = open(PATH_FILE_OWNER, O_CREAT); close(fd); 
fd = open(PATH_FILE_CAR, O_CREAT); close(fd);

It s now the first line of my program and now the file exist. I have always same error

Comment: Like @mhawke suggested above, use perror() after any call that fails, to get a better description of what the problem is.  And make sure you check for errors on all of the calls, so that you're not trying to figure out what's wrong with the read() when it was your open() that had trouble, etc.